# Java operator overloading with strings+characters

Tags: java, operator-overloading

I'have doubt,if im asking wrong please correct me
Question is

```
        String s="hello";
        String s1=' ';//error
        String s2=s+' ';
```

I know line1 is correct and line 2 is wrong because we can initialize `char a= ' ';`
but am confused in line3 i read `+` operator in java can be used for concatenation with strings
but it accepts characters like `' '` what is the reason ?

Comment: Because that's how Java is implemented.

Comment: Similar to doing `s + 5`, it's casted to String. For non-primitives, `toString()` will be called

Comment: Vince Emigh yes i do

Comment: Side note: If `s` is a `String` and `a` and `b` are integers, be careful with something like `s + a + b`.  This is not the same as `s + (a + b)`.  The first one converts each integer to a string and appends the strings in turn.  The second one adds the integers first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` operator is heavily overloaded. It takes almost anything.

If either side is a String, then the other will be converted to a String. That works with `char` as well as for other primitive types. For Objects, `toString()` is called (after a null-check).

Comment: please explain this too String s2=s+''; is error
String s2=s+' '; is works fine String s2=s+'a'; is works

Comment: @jenuine It looks like your first example has two single quote marks, i.e. `String s2 = s + ''`?  This just isn't legal syntax.  Single quote marks are used for character literals, and you can't have a character literal with no characters.  (Or with 2 or more characters.)  The Java compiler will not accept `''` _anywhere_.

Answer (score 2):

JLS 15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +

If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

Answer (score 1):

[JLS 5.4 String Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.4) says,

> String conversion applies only to an operand of the binary `+` operator which is not a String when the other operand is a String.
>
> In this single special case, the non-String operand to the `+` is converted to a String (§5.1.11) and evaluation of the `+` operator proceeds as specified in §15.18.1.